# Floating point number precision in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to use some formula, but I can't deal with the result, decimal point uncontrollable.

if  I set W.value=30  R.value= 1

```
          let endresult = 
           Math.round(((W*(36/(37 - R)))+
          (W*(1 + 0.0333 * R))+
          ((100 * W)/(101.3 - 2.67123*R))+
          (W* (Math.pow(R,0.1)))+
          ( (100 * W)/(52.2 +(41.9 *(Math.pow(2.71828,-0.055*R)))))+
          (W*(1 + 0.025 * R))+ 
          ((100 * W)/(48.8 + (53.8 * 
          ((Math.pow(2.71828,-0.075*R)))))))/7)

          for(let i=0 ;i <6 ;i++){
          if(endresult<500 && endresult>0){
          let newul = document.querySelector('#newul')
          let newli = document.createElement('li')
          newli.id="result"
          let frag =document.createDocumentFragment()
          let newtext =document.createTextNode(`${"1RM "+ 
          (i+5)+"0%:"+endresult*(((i+5)*10)/100)+"kg"}`)
          frag.appendChild(newtext)
          frag.appendChild(newli)
          newul.appendChild(frag)
          }
          =
          1RM 50%:15.5kg
          1RM 60%:18.599999999999998kg     
          1RM 70%:21.7kg
          1RM 80%:24.8kg
          1RM 90%:27.900000000000002kg      
          1RM 100%:31kg
```

I don’t want to have those extra decimal places, best can round the result, and I try to use "number-precision" / "Bignumber" to precise the result or Math.round, converted to String but still like a mess. 
It's any other way I can do?

Comment: Are you asking how round a number to a specific precision? For example, how to round `123.456789` to `123.46` ?

Comment: Best bet is to just use ``result.toFixed(precision)`` - it's designed for presentation which is what I'm assuming you're looking for.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including how you output the results of this formula. Then show what output you get and explain how you want it to be different.

Comment: @AlexWayne  
Yes, that's what I trying to do or just integer.

Comment: @ShawnLaFrance I try to use toFixed() before I using npm package to fix, but not working.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice OK, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thank you for adding some more code to show what you are doing. The code block should only include code. For example, don't say "If I set..."; just show the code that does it. It will also help to format your code following standard conventions. This will make it easier for us to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  got it ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript function toFixed(numberOfDecimals).
[See this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)